# How to get the path of an image in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have a image found in the storyboard and now i need to find the path of the image. How to get the path from the below found image?

// Code in which i have the image.

```
   Image imgFound= FindControl<Image>((UIElement)Layout, typeof(Image), strSelectedimg);
    string str=imgFound.Source.Tostring();
```

If i give the second line i get the result in the string variable as **"System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage"** but not the path. If i see through the debugging i can get the path in the "Uri" but how to get the "Uri" in codebehind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imgFound.Source` is of type **"System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage"**.  In order to access the properties that you see when debugging you need to cast it to a BitmapImage first.

You cast it like any other object,

```
var bmp = (BitmapImage)imgFound.Source;
```

once you have bmp you can access any of it's properties, e.g.

```
var uri = bmp.UriSource;
```